# TI CC2541 adc voltage divider wrong values

Tags: c, bluetooth, embedded, bluetooth-lowenergy, iar

I am working on a project with TI CC2541 (placed on a jdy-08 BLE module). I try to get a lipo battery level by using adc interface. I refered this post https://sunmaysky.blogspot.com/2013/12/cc2530-adc-howto-in-ti-z-stack.html?m=1 . To read adc value i use this code:

```
        uint16 adc_ain2=0;
        HalAdcSetReference(HAL_ADC_REF_125V);
        adc_ain2=HalAdcRead(HAL_ADC_CHN_AIN2,HAL_ADC_RESOLUTION_10);
```

If i dont use voltage divider and directly connect a voltage source to P0_2 pin there is no problem.
eg:

```
0,35V ==> adc 170 
0,70V ==> adc 310
1,17V ==> adc 498
```

But if i use a voltage divider i get wrong values (R1 = 820K, R2 = 820K).
eg:

```
0,33V ==> adc 347
0,53V ==> adc 368
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Have you tried to decrease the resistance of your resistor divider? The datasheet lists an input resistance of 197kOhm. Probably try something around 10kOhm.

Comment: If you search the web for "loaded voltage divider" there is a lot of content which helps you to understand why your voltage divider's output resistance is to high for the given ADC and the divider will not output half of the input voltage.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about electronics and belongs on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Alexander thank you.  "loaded voltage divider" keyword search solved the problem.